# Populate and submit “content creation” form programmatically?

Tags: forms

[image]

I have simple database table with two fields **"Title"** and **"URL"**.

Can we pull the values from database table **programmatically** and **populate** the above form with **"Title"** and **"URL"** and finally **submit** (save) it programmatically.

Comment: @shrish please before ask a question first search to it ,some question like this is popular and several time ask and answered.

Comment: @zhilevan I did my best sir.

Comment: @shrish , ok. I tell you welcome to drupal.stackexchange.com and hope you get your question answers and in future you will answer newbie questions. :) ;)